# Asp.net mvc3.0 server side javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making a custom helper in mvc 3  and I m using the following line in .cs(class) page

```
"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\" onClick=\"showOk()\";\" /><div class='messagepop pop' style='display: none'><form action='' method='post' id='new_message'><div><img src='../Images/x.png' alt='Exit'  class='msgPopImg'  onclick='closePop()' /><table bgcolor='#FFF0F0' rules='rows'>" + builder + "</table></div></form></div><script type='text/javascript'>function showOk() {var maskHeight = $(document).height();var maskWidth = $(window).width();$('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight }); $('.pop').show('fast', function () { });$('#mask').show();} function closePop() {$('.pop').hide(); $('#mask').hide();}", buttonText);
```

I m getting 'Input string was not in a correct format' error due to this part:-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function
showOk() {var maskHeight = $(document).height();var maskWidth = $(window).width();$('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight }); $('.pop').show('fast', function () { });$('#mask').show();} function closePop() {$('.pop').hide(); $('#mask').hide();}
"
```

**The modified code is:-**

```
"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\" onClick=\"showOk()\";\" /><div class='messagepop pop' style='display: none'><form action='' method='post' id='new_message'><div><img src='../Images/x.png' alt='Exit'  class='msgPopImg'  onclick='closePop()' /><table bgcolor='#FFF0F0' rules='rows'>" + builder + "</table></div></form></div><script type='text/javascript'>function showOk() {var maskHeight = 1000px;var maskWidth =1000px;$('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight }); $('.pop').css('display', 'block');$('#mask').css('display', 'block');} function closePop() {$('.pop').css('display', 'none'); $('#mask').css('display', 'none');}", buttonText);
```

How can I solve this error plz let me know

Comment: start with using `TagBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a closing `</script>` tag in your code. You have that?

**Update:**
Try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="{0}" onclick="showOk();" />
<div class='messagepop pop' style='display: none'>
    <form action='' method='post' id='new_message'>
    <div>
        <img src='../Images/x.png' alt='Exit' class='msgPopImg' onclick='closePop()' />
        <table bgcolor='#FFF0F0' rules='rows'>
            " + builder + "</table>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showOk() {
    var maskHeight = '1000px';
    var maskWidth = '1000px';
    $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight }); 
    $('.pop').css('display', 'block');
    $('#mask').css('display', 'block');
} 
function closePop() {
    $('.pop').css('display', 'none'); 
    $('#mask').css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have added closing tag but still it make no difference.

Comment: May be now                                      $('.pop').css('display', 'block');
$('#mask').css('display', 'block');

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick has too many quotes and note the extra one after your onclick event but still in your tag and your semicolon is out of the quote too

input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\" onClick=\"showOk()\";\"

Try
input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\" onClick=\"showOk();\"

Also are you using string.format since you have the {0}
I'm on my phone and can't see it if you are :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 'Input string was not in a correct format' because of the brackets '{' in the javascript part. It tries to evaluate the expression like it is {0} for example.

Where you want to render brackets you have to use '{{' instead of '{'.

P.S. Don't forget the closing bracket should also be '}}' instead of '}'.

**Update:**

Try with this string:

```
string.Format("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\" onClick=\"showOk()\";\" /><div class='messagepop pop' style='display: none'><form action='' method='post' id='new_message'><div><img src='../Images/x.png' alt='Exit'  class='msgPopImg'  onclick='closePop()' /><table bgcolor='#FFF0F0' rules='rows'>" + builder + "</table></div></form></div><script type='text/javascript'>function showOk() {{var maskHeight = $(document).height();var maskWidth = $(window).width();$('#mask').css({{ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight }}); $('.pop').show('fast', function () {{ }});$('#mask').show();}} function closePop() {{$('.pop').hide(); $('#mask').hide();}}", buttonText);
```

Comment: I tried your string with changed brackets and it passed. You probably missed some bracket.